# How to change the page title without changing the navigation bar title in Ionic v1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, title

When I change the ion-view title attribute the title is changing on the navigation bar and browser tab. However, I just want to change the title on the browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i get what you mean but i think the attribute title works like that

```
<ion-view title="Ingredients" id="page2">
```

of course this change won't lead to anything since they don't show on the app but i hope my answer could help

Comment: I know how this tag works and how title attribute works. I just need to change the title for the browser tab without changing the navigation bar title.